# firestore update list overlap value increment not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, increment

```
void testing() {
  var list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 8];
  var up = {for (var item in list) '$item': FieldValue.increment(1)};
  testdb.doc('test').update(up);
}


// fireStore result 
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1 
8: 1

why???? 3: 1
i think 3: 2
```

firestore update list overlap value increment not working
help me

Comment: I don't know if FieldValue.increment() works in premade object. Have you tested using multiple increment() for every field you want to update in your doc().update(? If that works then the problem lies in premade object.